# How to reflect result of review on GitHub

Tags: git, github

In generally, should I (=contributor) merge two commits before pushing code which is pointed out in review on GitHub and fixed by me?

```
$ git commit -am "Reflect the result of review"
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
・・・merge two commits and delete the above commit message by squash option
$ git push -f origin [branch for this pull request]
```

In other words, the second step (`git rebase ...`) is needed?

**Edit:** To avoid a misunderstanding, I added "(=contributor)" to the above. So that, "I" means a contributor, not reviewer, in this question.

Comment: I would say that in general, no, you should _not_ do this, because it appears that you are rewriting the history of a branch which might be shared with other developers.  You should only use this option if you are certain that no one else has this branch checked out with the intention of also contributing to it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, to compress x number of revisions into a single one? That's one possibility.... but I prefer to do it like this:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2 # take branch pointer two revisions back... it can be n changes, all changes are saved into the index ready to be committed
git commit -m "My feature"
```

Then you can push or whatever you consider you should do with the branch.

Comment: You might want to comment on the possible side effects of rewriting the history of a published Git branch.

Comment: The OP is running `git rebase -i`... so it's the same **sin**. No point.